# Input fields value not changing in click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my previous code I have used two separate input fields `%` and `$` value. `%` value code:

```
<td>
    <input name="propertytaxpc" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax; ?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />
    %
</td>
```

**`$` value code:**

```
<td> 
    $ 
    <input name="propertytaxamt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxAmountChanged(true)"  />
</td>
```

In my new code I have `input` fields changed the two fields to one field. `%` and `$` values both load single input fields loan. I have set `%` and `$` icon on click. Now input fields default `%` icon also `%`. When the user changes icon `%` to `$` the value also needs to change.

```
<div class="col-md-3 padding-rht">
    <input name="propertytaxpc" class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax;?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />


</div>

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft">
    <img src="Content/Images/percent.png" onclick="changeColor(event,this.src)" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</div>
```

```js
function changeColor(event, _src) {
    var fname = _src;
    var ImageName = fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //alert(ImageName);
    if (ImageName == "percent.png") {
        $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/RedDoller.png");
    }
    else {
        $(event.target).attr("src", "Content/Images/percent.png");
   }
}
```

Can any one take look? I have tried many methods, but they're not working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have used onchange event on textbox, so js functions will be called when value in textbox changed

Comment: i have used onchange function not working @user3782114

Comment: you call changeColor1() in the img but the function is changeColor()... is it a typo?

Comment: Edited  is type of image change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but if I understand correctly I think what you're trying to achieve is for the percent and amount fields to switch visibility according to the $/% image, right?

If so, what you need to do is toggle the two input fields' visibilty, along with changing the image source. Try the code below:

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<div class="col-md-3 padding-rht">
    <input id="pct" name="propertytaxpc" class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="<?php echo $dproperty_tax;?>" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />

    <input id="amt" name="propertytaxamt" class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxAmountChanged(true)"  />
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft">
    <img id="change" src="Content/Images/percent.png" onclick="changeColor(event,this.src)" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#amt").hide();

    $("#change").click(function() {
        changeColor(this);
    });
});

function changeColor(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var ImageName = $elem.attr("src");
    ImageName = ImageName.substring(ImageName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if (ImageName == "percent.png") {
        $elem.attr("src", "Content/Images/RedDoller.png");
    } else {
        $elem.attr("src", "Content/Images/percent.png");
    }
    $("#pct, #amt").toggle();
}
```

An example JS fiddle demonstrating the technique is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ds8txa1j/

Comment: i want two value single input fields  . values change when user select Doller  image tot percent image.that time need to change the value

Comment: Jsfiddle its Working ..i have used your code not Working

Comment: Did you make sure you added the IDs to the `input` and `img` elements? If it still doesn't work please post the updated code in your question so we can see it.

Comment: OK @bercohol i will upload

Comment: OK there were several problems with your fiddle: 1. You didn't add the `id` attribute to your input fields, 2. Your second field was still hidden, it should be a text type, and 3. The fiddle did not include jQuery, which it depends on. I've updated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/v5gsru3p/1/

Comment: thank you @beercohol i will check with your code . thanks

Comment: thank you so much for your help Really helped me lot

Answer (score 0):

This way it works to me. No jquery or extra lib used. There some alert just to check it works...

```
  <div class="col-md-3 padding-rht">
    <input name="propertytaxpc" class="txt" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" value="aaa" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxPcChanged(true)" />

    <input name="propertytaxamt" class="txt" type="hidden" size="8" maxlength="8" onChange="javascript:propertyTaxAmountChanged(true)"  />
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft">
    <img src="Content/Images/percent.png" onclick="javascript:changeColor1(this);" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

function changeColor1(elem) {
    var fname = elem.src;
    var ImageName = fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    alert(ImageName);
    if (ImageName == "percent.png") {
        elem.src = "Content/Images/RedDoller.png";
    }
    else {
        elem.src = "Content/Images/percent.png";
   }
   alert(elem.src);
}
</script>
```

Comment: i have checked your code Not Working jsfiddle @Jkike   please take a look

Comment: check your configuration on jsfiddle. It's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4uhngq0c/

Comment: i need to change value when user change image

Comment: change the value of what exactly?

Comment: actually i have two value $ and % value.previous code have  separate input fields have . in my new both two value pass single input. i have used % and $ image icon.    user change % to $ value need to change